# iPhone: Open local html page with flip transformation

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

HI,

I am using following code to open WebView. It opens Apple site without any animation. I want to open local html page with animation(e.g. flip transformation) and want to have a Back button so that I can go to my main aplication again. Could anyone please help me with this.

```
CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
NSString *urlAddress = @"www.apple.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code after you add your webview as subview to self.view.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDelay:    0.0f ];       // in seconds  
     [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f ];       // in seconds
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                           forView:self.view 
                             cache:YES]; 

         [self.view addSubview:webView];

     [UIView commitAnimations ];
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have added your code as you said with animation duration 3 seconds but it didn't make any difference! Also could you tell me how to add the back button? Do I have to create NavigationBar?

Comment: I modified the code sample  - forView:self.view     and  put the 'addSubview' call inside the animation block.  If you have a UINavigationController (not bar), you can push your web view onto the navController and you'll get a back button automatically.

Comment: @Mike: I am bit confused. I have only main view & no other tabs. I have info button that opens html page. I added following code after animation block but it doesn't work. `code` UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
 [backButton release];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES]; `code`

Comment: Is your webView animating in the way you want it to?

Comment: Yep. WebView animating perfectly but NavigationController is not getting added. I thought it might getting hidden because I am setting WebView frame to screen size but that's also not true. I have created NIB file with WebView and UIToolBar(with Button as UIBarButtonItem) and used following code. It works fine now. `code`     
    AppInfoScreen * ais = [[AppInfoScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppInfoScreen" bundle:nil];
 [ais setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
 [self presentModalViewController:ais animated:YES];
 [ais release]; `code`

Comment: So "it works fine now", including your navController?  If not, how are you declaring it - is it null when you try to push to it?  That's the most common problem.

Comment: Yep. it works fine including navController but I have changed the total implementation as I said. I used NIB file now and another controller class. Not sure why it wasn't working when I set self.navigationController. I haven't declared it. I used directly self.navigationController property and set NavigationBarHidden to NO. Created Back button manually etc as given in my one my previous posts code.

Comment: When you use a NIB (and an IBOutlet), loading the NIB instantiates the nav controller automatically.  Without a NIB, you have to declare and instantiate the navCon programmatically.  Objective-C allows you to send messages to nil objects, so you were trying to push a view controller onto a nil navigation controller.  It compiles, runs, does not crash, but does not work.  Personally, I hate this "feature" of Objective-C. Glad you got it running.